# XUL textbox setSelectionRange

Tags: javascript, xul, xulrunner

I wonder if the routine setSelectionRange the textbox does not work in new Firefox summers. In the MDN site (Mozilla Developer Center) it was specified:

> setSelectionRange( start, end )
>       Return type: no return value 
>       Sets the selected portion of the textbox, where the start argument is the index of the first character to select and the end argument is
>   the index of the character after the selection. Set both arguments to
>   the same value to move the cursor to the corresponding position
>   without selecting text.

```xml
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<window id="yourwindow"
        xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
        xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<button label="x"  oncommand="sel()"  />

<textbox id="id" multiline="true"  
         value="This is some text that could wrap onto multiple lines."/>  

<script type="text/javascript">
<![CDATA[
function sel(){
var textbox = document.getElementById("id");
textbox.setSelectionRange( 1 , 2 );
}
]]>
</script>
</window>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection

Answer (score 1):

The function works just fine. However, when you click a button the input focus is (logically) on the button and `setSelectionRange` won't change that. You can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to select the text field and make the selection visible. Alternatively, you can also add this line to your `sel()` function to focus the text field:

```js
textbox.focus();
```

Comment: @user916933: Feel free to accept the answer if it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: would be possible to select multiple parts of a sentence?

Comment: @user916933: Text fields don't support multiple selection.